# jQuery HTML Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What is a good way to ignore the tags/variables in a jQuery HTML method?

For instance, if there was no value for company, it would not be included in the HTML.

```
$('.modal-body').html(`
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Name:</span> ${name}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Company:</span> ${company}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Job:</span> ${job}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Title:</span> ${title}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Phone:</span> ${phone}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Email:</span> ${email}</p>
            <p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Event Loc:</span> ${addressResult}</p>
    `)
```

Comment: You can use IF-STATEMENT. `if(${company}) $('.modal-body').html(``)`

Comment: `name` is a global variable attached to the Window object. It's best practice to not use "name" as the name of a variable.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: I assume you are looking to simply add a blank string for items in your node list that are not included in a particular object? For ex if your object has name, job, title, phone, email, then you want the missing entries to parse as an empty string for those particular missing variable values, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I frown on using ternary operators for major control flow, inline conditionals are very useful for situations like this.

```js
const name = "John Smith",
  company = "1-800-Flowers",
  job = "Software Developer",
  title = undefined,
  phone = "(123)-456-7890",
  email = "john@smith.com",
  addressResult = "123 Big Street, Town, MA"

$('.modal-body').html(`
            ${name ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Name:</span> ${name}</p>` : ""}
            ${company ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Company:</span> ${company}</p>` : ""}
            ${job ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Job:</span> ${job}</p>` : ""}
            ${title ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Title:</span> ${title}</p>` : ""}
            ${phone ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Phone:</span> ${phone}</p>` : ""}
            ${email ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Email:</span> ${email}</p>` : ""}
            ${addressResult ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Event Loc:</span> ${addressResult}</p>` : ""}
    `)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement like this:

```js
let htmlContent = `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Job:</span> ${job}</p>`;
if(company) {
 htmlContent += `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Company:</span> ${company}</p>`;
}
$('.modal-body').html(htmlContent);
```

Or using ternary operators like this:

```js
$('.modal-body').html(`
  ${job ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Job:</span> ${job}</p>` : ''}
  ${company ? `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Company:</span> ${company}</p>` : ''}
`);
```

And also please change ${name} because it's a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the form of an array of objects (like a common JSON) and you need to display the data of a single object on a modal, you'll need to be able to select an object and extract the keys and values of said object (See **Figure I**)

### Figure I

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Simple modal with a unordered list. The <ul> will be the targeted element -->
<dialog>
  <ul></ul>
</dialog>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```js
// Data source as an array of objects (simular to JSON)
const data = [
  { "keyA": "value1", "keyB": "value2" }, 
  { "keyA": "value3", "keyB": "" }, 
  { "keyA": "value5", "keyB": "value6" }
]; 

// Select object by index number and extract data
let index = 1; // Second object

function displayData(data, index) {
  // Clear <ul>
  $("ul").html("");

  /* Convert object into an array of key/value pairs
  || keyValuePairs = [["keyA": "value3"], ["keyB", ""]];
  */
  const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(data[index]);
  
  // Add and format each key/value pair into <ul>
  keyValuePairs.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // IF value exists...
    if (value) {
      $("ul").append(
        `<li>
           <b> // Same as <span style="font-weight: bold">
             ${key.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+key.slice(1)}: // Capitalize key
           </b> 
           &nbsp;${value}
        </li>`
      );
    }
  });
}
```

**Result**

```html
<!-- 
Result is the data of the second object is displayed in <ul>
Note, keyB is excluded since it had no value
-->
<dialog>
  <ul>
    <li><b>KeyA:</b> value3</li>
  </ul>
</dialog>
```

The following example is a live version of the code above with a `<select>` that will allow you to change profiles.

### Example

```js
const profiles = [{
  "name": "Lucille Blay",
  "company": "Tambee",
  "title": "Technical Writer",
  "phone": "",
  "email": "lblay0@arstechnica.com",
  "address": ""
}, {
  "name": "Baudoin Macauley",
  "company": "",
  "title": "",
  "phone": "877-812-9835",
  "email": "bmacauley1@utexas.edu",
  "address": "415 David Way"
}, {
  "name": "Aurora Garside",
  "company": "",
  "title": "Nuclear Power Engineer",
  "phone": "823-514-0402",
  "email": "agarside2@linkedin.com",
  "address": ""
}];

function displayProfile(profiles, index) {
  $("ul").html("");
  let data = Object.entries(profiles[index]);
  data.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value) {
      $("ul").append(
        `<li>
         <b>
           ${key.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+key.slice(1)}:
         </b> 
         &nbsp;${value}
       </li>`);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * For Demo Purposes Only [START]
 */
$("select").on("input", function(e) {
  displayProfile(profiles, this.value);
  this.value = "Pick Index Number";
  $("dialog")[0].showModal();
});

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  $("dialog")[0].close();
});
// [END]
```

```css
:root {
  font: 300 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

select {
  padding: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

dialog {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

button {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  left: 16px;
  float: right;
  height: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- For Demo Purposes Only [START] -->
<select>
  <option selected>Pick Index Number</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<!-- [END] -->

<dialog>
  <button>X</button>
  <ul></ul>
</dialog>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure where the *customer info* is coming from but if its an array of object, you can do something like the following.

```js
const customers = [{
  name: 'John Doe',
  company: null,
  job: 'Front-End Developer',
  title: 'manager',
  phone: '555-555-5555',
  email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
  addressResult: null
}]

function getInfo(k, v){
  return v !== null ? $('.modal-body').append(`<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">${k}:</span> ${v}</p>`) : null  
}

$.each(customers, function(index, value){
  $.each(value, function(i,v){    
   getInfo(i,v)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body"></div>
```